# Move folders from 'on my mac' to gmail imap

Tags: mail.app, data-synchronization, email, gmail

I want to start organizing my emails on the cloud, directly in my gmail account, instead of locally 'on my mac'.  Is there any way to migrate my current folders (and their e-mails) onto gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your local message show up in Mail you can just drag and drop them into the IMAP folders using the Mail sidebar I believe. Is that what you are asking about?[image]